# QStyledItemDelegate проблема с сохранением введённых данных

Tags: python, c++, sql, qt

Когда жму энтер, или меняю фокус курсора на другую кнопку (но не на другую строку в таблице, тогда всё работает), то данные не сохраняются, при энтер вообще выделяются почему-то. setModelData не вызывается при нажатии на энтер.

***sqlsuppliernumberformatdelegate.h***:

```
#ifndef SQLSUPPLIERNUMBERFORMATDELEGATE_H
#define SQLSUPPLIERNUMBERFORMATDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    explicit SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    QString displayText(const QVariant& value, const QLocale& locale) const override;
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    bool eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // SQLSUPPLIERNUMBERFORMATDELEGATE_H
```

***sqlsuppliernumberformatdelegate.cpp***:

```
#include "sqlsuppliernumberformatdelegate.h"
#include "doublespinbox.h"
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QValidator>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QComboBox>

SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {
}

QString SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::displayText(const QVariant& value, const QLocale& locale) const {
    switch(static_cast<QMetaType::Type>(value.type())){
        case QMetaType::Float:
            return locale.toString(value.toFloat(), 'f', 0);
        case QMetaType::Double:
            return locale.toString(value.toDouble(), 'f', 0);
        default:
            return QStyledItemDelegate::displayText(value, locale);
    }
}

QWidget* SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const {
    DoubleSpinBox* editor = new DoubleSpinBox(parent);
    return editor;
}

void SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    double value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toDouble();
    DoubleSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<DoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
    spinBox->setValue(value);
}

void SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    DoubleSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<DoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
    spinBox->interpretText();
    double value = spinBox->value();

    model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
}

void SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}

bool SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent* event) {
    return event->type() == QEvent::Wheel;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение состояло в ручной отправке сигналов о том, что редактирование завершено:

```
QWidget* SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex&) const {
    DoubleSpinBox* editor = new DoubleSpinBox(parent);
    connect(editor, &DoubleSpinBox::editingFinished, this, &SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::endEditor);
    return editor;
}
```

Метод, отсылающий сигналы:

```
void SqlSupplierNumberFormatDelegate::endEditor() {
    commitData(qobject_cast<DoubleSpinBox*>(sender()));
    closeEditor(qobject_cast<DoubleSpinBox*>(sender()));
}
```